# AmazonS3ClientBuilder Issue

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using WowzaStreamingEngine and IAM roles for AmazonS3 operations but facing and issue regarding AmazonS3ClientBuilder. Logs before that line gets printed but not after AmazonS3ClientBuilder line. Even No exception occurs. Just Application stucks over there.

```
try{
    // AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient() //After this line

    AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()   //or after this line.
    .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
    .build();
    WMS_LOGGER.info("s3 : " + s3);
} catch(Exception e ){
    WMS_LOGGER.info("Exception : "+e);
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to tag your question correctly, else you will not reach the experts for your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to set your **Credentials** instead of **false**

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
  .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
  .build();
```

and i think this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-java) will help you

Comment: Thanks fathy

But instead of credentials, I have to use IAM roles.
and one more thing, I have also added test cases where these operations are getting performed successfully but it stucks only in main application. Still not getting sure what is the main issue there.
I am using WowzaStreamingEngine 4.7.7
aws-java-sdk 1.11.651